# Footer Div, 3 columns, with images and text

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to get the footer of my site, which has three columns that consist of three vector icons and text, to span the width of the site. I'd like the text to be underneath the icons and for each icon and text block to be centered and divided evenly in the center. The code I have is producing a vertical line between the columns that is white, when I want the entire length of the footer to be a material purple. It also does not span the width of the site. Here is my HTML:

```
<footer>
<div>
 <img src="http://minimalwebdesigns412.com/Images/Oval2_Group@2x.png"   alt="Responsive" width="150" height="150">
    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.</section>
        </div>
<div>   
 <img src="http://minimalwebdesigns412.com/Images/Oval1_Group@2x.png" alt="Cloud" width="150" height="150">
     <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.</section>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://minimalwebdesigns412.com/Images/Oval3_Shape@2x.png" alt="Email" width="150" height="150">
    <section> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.</section>
 </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
    footer div {
    width: 32%;
    background: rgba(113,15,154,0.73);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.00);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow-x: none;

    }

footer div section {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: inherit;
    }
```

You can find my test site here:

http://test.minimalwebdesigns412.com

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
footer {
 background: rgba(113,15,154,0.73);
}

footer div {
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.00);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

footer div section {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

**JSBIN:** http://jsbin.com/yuwataluni/1/

Comment: Download and use bootstrap. Perfect for the layout you desire http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Make your  position:relative and your footer

```
footer{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
}
```

You have other issue going with your css, but put all your footer html in side the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Give the 3 divs a width of 33.333%, and float them in the footer.  Then clear the float.  See the demonstration below.  The red outline is the container - could be your page body.  Also, replace the image size declarations with a single percent style, and you can then set the container width to anything you like, and the 3 divs (and images) will scale.

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  width: 800px;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
}
footer div {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  background: rgba(113, 15, 154, 0.73);
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow-x: none;
  text-align: center;
}
footer div section {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: inherit;
}
footer div img {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <footer>
    <div>
      <img src="http://minimalwebdesigns412.com/Images/Oval2_Group@2x.png" alt="Responsive">
      <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.</section>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://minimalwebdesigns412.com/Images/Oval1_Group@2x.png" alt="Cloud">
      <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.</section>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://minimalwebdesigns412.com/Images/Oval3_Shape@2x.png" alt="Email">
      <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.</section>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both">
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// make the footer completely purple
footer {
    background: rgba(113, 15, 154, 0.73);
}

// to span the width of the site
// divided evenly
// icons and text center
footer div {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Please note:
- you didn't have a the footer close tag

JSBIN http://jsbin.com/giqabiravi/1/

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Yeah I had to build this for class and the prof wanted it a way I didn't and the CSS is all janky.